# Using Jenkins to deploy to a Linux server and then run selenium test from a windows server

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, multiplatform

I am currently trying to deploy a website in PHP to a Linux server using jenkins and then use the same job to run a set of selenium test cases using python on a windows server, I can do both of these things individually but can not find a way to do them both within the same job.

I have tried using the Execute shell setting and then Executing a windows shell but do not know how to tell the job that these are different servers or if this is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to do both in the same job?
If you want job B to run only after Job A was completed successfully, You could have job A trigger Job B by using 'Add post-build action' in Job A configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I thought it would be a neater solution to have the deployment and test in 1 job, we do this with other test jobs but there the tests and deployment are on the same server, I am at a loss as to why this is not easily possible in a single job.